# Multi-site in one Wagtail installation

Tags: wagtail

If I have several sites in one Wagtail installation, is it possible to have one database for each site or all sites are saved in the same database?

Answer (score 1):

All sites are saved in the same database. Of course, if you really need separate databases, there's nothing to stop you from setting up a separate Wagtail installation for each one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python scripts to fetch Data from the main multisite database into private DBs for each website, of course you need to have knowledge with DBs by python & of course for each DATABASE engine you need different scripting..!

search on Google or StackOverflow (DB & python).. and good luck